# Do savings and subtotal need to be displayed on a product page?

Tags: user-behavior, copywriting, e-commerce, user-centered-design, pricing

We are designing a product page and I think having money you saved and subtotal is redundant as it appears in cart and during checkout. My colleagues think "You saved a total of $XX.XX" is crucial.  Do you think it's redundant?

Examples of product pages that show money saved and subtotals for regular and sale products.[image: Americanblinds.com wallpaper product page]

[image]

- http://www.rockport.com/castleton-boot/castletonboot.html
- http://www.rockport.com/ledge-hill-boot/lhbootoutlet.html?dwvar_lhbootoutlet_color=lhbootoutlet_lighttan&start=1&cgid=sal-mens-all-mens-sale
- http://www.americanblinds.com/wallpaper/productid,51623

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't hide pricing information from the buyer, especially if there's a chance that information could inspire them to "Proceed to checkout".

Also, if they don't see the savings there, they might go to another site to look.

Comment: Not only that, they might be confused why it's showing on one page, but not the other. 

Through the whole process you show them EVERYTHING related to pricing because when people are buying things, that's what they are mostly concerned with: "how much is this going to cost?"

Comment: In addition to that, if you don't have it on the product page that it's on sale, how are they going to know? Also, people are more likely to buy things that are on sale than something that isn't because what comes into their mind when they consider an item on sale is "this looks good, and it's on sale... I can save money now, because I like it, instead of buy it later, when I still would like it."

Comment: Thanks for the help.  One obstacle we have is showing original price and subtotal; I've only seen one other site  where it's done well. They show list price, price and savings.  http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0038W0K2K/ref=s9_simh_gw_p23_d0_i1?pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_s=center-2&pf_rd_r=1FJFKNG92NSG9W8V0Q6E&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=1389517282&pf_rd_i=507846

Answer (score 3):

Studies done on the [effects of price/promotion framing on price expectations and choice](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aNjd2nPftXwEJ%3awww.marketingpower.com/AboutAMA/Pages/AMA%2520Publications/AMA%2520Journals/Journal%2520of%2520Marketing/TOCs/summary%2520july%252007/CentsorPercentjmjuly07.aspx%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk) indicate that there are definite eCommerce benefits to offering this information to users at the product display page level.

Also useful to decide how this information is displayed and whether to use cost saving, percentage saving or a combination of both.

Some useful tips and examples can be found at;

http://sixrevisions.com/user-interface/product-page-design/

http://econsultancy.com/uk/blog/63462-ecommerce-product-pages-where-to-place-30-elements-and-why

Hope this helps.

Comment: No problem - glad they were useful :)

Answer (score 1):

Information is king! I think the problem lies in how you are displaying the information to the user, the primary data is how much the user is paying and this should be made the most prominent.

However, the secondary data is something likely to inspire them, Saved $10 (5%) is great information.

Always test test test with users and see what they think, you could have a 'like' button next to discount to see if any one clicks it.

Answer (score 1):

N=1 here but I think you should always show what people are saving. I would also always show the % next to a monetary value.

Reason behind it is that 4 dollars might not sound like a lot. But if that 4 dollars means 55% OFF it will definitely make people thing they are getting a good deal, which will mean you increase sales.

Answer (score 1):

One of the reasons why people purchase items online is to save money. 
I would make the saving the second prominent information, being the first one the final price of the item.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the most known example of money savings is [Black Friday](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Friday_%28shopping%29). People are awared of savings, so do your examples.
[image]

So it could work to increase the sales. But it isn't only trick, you could find more, for example, in the [Neuro Web Design: What Makes Them Click?](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321603605) by S. Weinschenk.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking for opinion, so here's mine.

Giving the user as much information as possible, as long as it doesn't detract from the buying process, is very important. If they are making savings as they add items to their cart then tell them this.

Of course human nature is very fickle, if you have the opportunity you could run a week long test with each type of information displayed and check the analytic's against conversion rates and check the drop-off points.

I think the 'Ledge Hill Boot' example works particularly well.